# Is there a way to check open/click rates, bounces of emails via Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm currently trying to send emails from a Rails application and would like to check the open/click rates of these emails. (without using any web service) Is there a gem or plugin that I can use to help me find out? Or is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varatis is correct, using image tracking is the most common way this is done, and it is the way that most web services provide you with analytics on the e-mails they send on your behalf. Here is [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525145/email-open-notification-ruby-on-rails) that includes an example of how you might do this in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-122920.html

I think the first mentioned method, detecting how many times an image has been viewed would be the easiest. Then again, these are not exact solutions, but I think an exact solution would be sort of a security hole (i.e. sending an HTTP request to a foreign server once you open an email).